AWS EC2 IAM variable based access to S3 buckets
I have a use case where I create an EC2 instance, and a bucket for it, and I want that EC2 instance to only access that bucket.
I saw that you can use variables such as aws:ResourceTag and aws:RequestTag, but I did not manage to get any variation to work.
Basically, I would like to create a IAM Role with a policy for my EC2 such that I add a tag on the instance, and it can only access the S3 bucket specified in the tag.
Is that possible?
My attempts:
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:RestoreObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ResourceTag/BucketTag": "${aws:RequestTag/BucketTag}"
                }
            }
        }

or
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:RestoreObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${aws:ResourceTag/BucketTag}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${aws:ResourceTag/BucketTag}/*"
            ],
        }


Since AWS is deny by default, if you only give the EC2 instance role permissions to access that bucket, then it can't access any other bucket that requires authnz.  For public bucket, you can DENY s3 actions with NotResource of your bucket.  For the inverse, making sure only that ec2 instance can access that bucket, use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-ec2-source-instance-arn in the bucket policy.

This looks interesting, but it would result in having to create a new Role for each bucket and to know the ec2 arn beforehand. I don't see how I could combine it with aws:ResourceTag? or am I mistaken

"such that I add a tag on the instance, and it can only access the S3 bucket specified in the tag." this is where your approach goes off the rails.  AFAIK there's no way to get from a tag on an EC2 instance to a policy that allows a role the instance uses to be tagged.  However if you're willing to tag the role instead, you can use Principal Tag.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html

Yeah, I thought about the principal tag, but if I assign the Role to more than one EC2 instances, then I won't get to achieve the result. I guess the only way to go forward is to create one Role per EC2

It's an interesting question and I looked for a while, but I can't see any way to use an ec2 instance tag as a principal context key for iam policies

It seems you want to:

Add a tag to an Amazon EC2 instance
Control which S3 bucket the instance can access based on that Tag value

This is not possible. The policy that grants access to the Amazon S3 bucket cannot refer to a tag on the EC2 instance.
An alternative approach is to put a bucket policy on the bucket itself that limits access based on an IAM Role, and I think the ARN can include the actual instance id so it is a combination of the IAM Role + Instance.
This might help: How to restrict Amazon S3 bucket access to a specific IAM role | AWS Security Blog
